# tumblr mobile not working with prettify.js

Tags: mobile, tumblr, pretty-print

So I wired in Prettify.js and Prettify.css into my new Tumblr blog.  It works out great in chrome, IE, and Firefox but I was astonished when I went to my Android Phone and suddenly the code inside ... looks like an atrocity.

I was about to go digging but figured before I spend hours trying to solve a problem someone else already fixed I would see if my ol' Stack Buddies have anything to say on the matter.

aquamoogle.tumblr.com

Any solutions will be greatly appreciated and if none are posted I'll likely toss up a solution by the end of the weekend.

**Clarification EDIT**  This is viewing the post through the Tumblr Android application.  I don't think it has anything to do with phone version but because someone is bound to ask it's a Motorola Droid Bionic running Android 2.3.4

Comment: Apparently Tumblr's mobile app isn't using the standard "web frame" application base that everyone else is using like Twitter and Facebook on the Android market.  This leaves me wondering if pretty-print code is even possible to render on Tumblr's mobile app.  This is a huge let down and I don't feel like styling my own code posts with syntax highlighting and css for EVERY post... If anyone has an ideas past this it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alrighty, since nobody came along with this one I'll throw the answer out there.  The Tumblr application after decompiling it off the APK does not use a standard web frame.  This means that javascript execution is not embedded in the view for the mobile application.

Sucks I know... Another possible solution would be to use straight CSS for formatting but alas this doesn't even work in the mobile version as the CSS sheets are overridden with mobile style sheets for more compact formatting.

So this one goes down as "unsolvable" due to the mobile application not operating within the same boundaries as the web driven blog does.

If someone does by chance have a solution to this that will work however, I would be interested in hearing it but at this time I don't have a valid solution.  But, it's good to know.

Comment: Thanks, figured this question would long be dead :-P Glad it was at least somewhat helpful to someone else